# How to bring facebook,twitter,linkedin chat in to one java application?

Tags: java, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate facebook,twitter,linkedin chat in to one java application. I was searching for the same in google but did not find any useful information, so please if any of you have already done or know how to do? Please do consider this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use restfb library for facebook integration

Use Twitter4J API for twitter integration 
http://twitter4j.org

Use Oauth library to integrate linkedln 
http://code.google.com/p/oauth/

Answer (score 1):

All these sites provide ChatApi you can use these API. Please look into developer site of each of them.

API for Facebook is -

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: I am sorry if i am wrong, i am looking for the same in java application integration but the sample is available for php i suppose

Comment: java can call HTTPClient to implement this.

Comment: please read full chat api document.